# search for a section of log that was appended upon execution of script

Tags: linux, grep, file-search

I'm using WebLogic start script `startmymanageserver1.sh` that writes(appends) to a `managedserver.log` log file every time it is executed.

The `managedserver.log` may have logs from the past few months which I cannot override.

I wish to `grep` for a string `Server is in RUNNING State` not from the entire `managedserver.log`; but only from the section of logs that was appended as a result of my executing the `startmymanageserver1.sh`

Can you please suggest how to grep from only the section of  `managedserver.log` that was updated as a result of my last run of `startmymanageserver1.sh`?

Comment: Does this log include any timestamps?

Comment: Does the `startmymanageserver1.sh` put anything in the log when it starts?

Answer (score 0):

this will search only within last 10 entries

```
tail -n10 managedserver.log | grep Server.is.in.RUNNING.State
```

this will search file bottom up

```
tac managedserver.log | grep -m1 Server.is.in.RUNNING.State
```